# Feedback for a circuit

Tags: circuit-design, design-rules

I am designing my first original circuit, which is a take on the 'Useless Box'. I have designed a schematic and I am seeking feedback on it. I am a complete newbie so most likely there will be some pretty obvious mistakes.

**A brief explanation**

The main input is a SPDT switch labelled action, this moves an arm, powered by one of the two motors, which changes the state of the SPDT switch, this moves a separate motor to move the arm back. Another SPDT switch detects the state of the arm and activates one of two 555 timers to flash an LED in roughly 1 second intervals.

**The schematic**

[image: The Schematic]

**Notes**

I have used a voltage regulator as the motors I am planning to use are 3.3 V and 0.28 A with no load

**Update**

[image: Updated]

I have updated the schematic according to jp314's suggestions, and have removed the CB4007 inverter and replaced it with a 4050 Hex Buffer. I also changed the input voltage from 9v to 5v because it works better with my choice of voltage regulator.

If there is any more information I need to provide let me know as I am very new to the digital design community.

Comment: It's SPDT not STPD I believe.

Comment: I'm glad you commented on your messy schematic, because it is. It doesn't do you any favours, because you can't read it, and it doesn't do us any favours, because we have to work very hard to read it as well. Positive to the top, ground at the bottom. Don't cross wires if you can avoid it. Every 3-way connection should be dotted, on the connection. 4-way connections are banned, a pair of wires crossing is just that, not a connection. It will be worth your time to take a look at other schematics, and rework this one. I can't see which are circuit mistakes, and which are schematic untidiness.

Comment: Thanks Neil I will update it soon with one that isn't as messy

Comment: The CD4007 is not a normal inverter, and probably will not function as shown. Please show pin numbers, because all of its internal stages are not identical. Consider changing the 4081 to a 4011 or 4093, which eliminated the need for the inverters.  Also, what is the function of C2 and C3? Also, there are several devices connected to a GND symbol, and several other devices connected to the 9 V battery - terminal. BUT, these two nets are not connected together.

Comment: @AnalogKid could you explain in more detail what you mean by 'devices connected to a GND symbol, and serveral other devices connect to the 9v battery terminal' and why this is a problem

Comment: In the updated schematic, D2 and D3 are connected to the negative end of BT1 with connection dots.  OTOH, C13 and C15 cross over the net to BT1 without connection dots, and then go to GND symbols.  I'm sure you intend a connection, but that is not what the schematic says, and that is not what pc board layout software would produce.

Comment: Thanks AnalogKid that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the 10k pulldowns on the NPN bases, but you might want a resistor in series between the buffer and the base. Choose a value about 20-50x the resistance of the relay coil.

You *do* need a pulldown R on the inputs of the logic gates (where 'Action drives). An open circuit input won't be a reliable logic '0' (or any state). 100k will do.

You *do* need a resistor in series with each LED. For indoor use choose one that gives 5-10 mA LED current.

C2 seems shorted -- not a problem, is it a spare?

Be careful with heat in your 3.3 V regulator. If the motors are loaded and consume (say) 0.6 A, the regulator will dissipate (9-3.3)*0.6 = 3.4 W. This is OK for a short while (few s), but for longer, it will need a small heatsink.